# Error in AWS Glue : Error downloading script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Intermittently getting the following error while running aws glue job,

Error downloading script: fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would be intermittent, but this is likely an issue connecting to S3. A few things to check:

- Glue Jobs run with an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role.html). You can check your Job details to see what it's currently set to. You should make sure that role has privileges to access the S3 bucket that has your job code in it.
- Glue Jobs require a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoints-s3.html). You should check to make sure that you have one properly created for the VPC you're using
- It is possible to configure a VPC endpoint without associating it with any subnets. Check your VPC Endpoint for the correct routing.

Below is a bit of reference code written with AWS CDK, in case it's helpful

**IAM Role**

```
new iam.Role(this, `GlueJobRole`, {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal(`glue.amazonaws.com`),
  managedPolicies: [
    iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
      `service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole`
    ),
  ],
});
```

**VPC Endpoint**

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, `VPC`, { vpcId: VPC_ID });

new ec2.GatewayVpcEndpoint(this, `S3VpcEndpoint`, {
  service: ec2.GatewayVpcEndpointAwsService.S3,
  subnets: vpc.publicSubnets,
  vpc,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your bucket is enabled customer managed key. You need to add Glue role to kms to fixed this issue.